# mvc perspective in zendframework

Tags: zend-framework, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I have a zend framework project, all written in one Module. Under this Module you find a controller directory, Model directory and view directory. I am looking for a perspective to devide this Module into many, each with its controllers, models and views. would you supply me with some references to read more about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should not divide your module, but introduce several modules. Each module has its own `config`, `src` and `view` folder. Inside the `src` folder is another folder (same name as Module) and in this `src` folder you find `controller`, `view` and `model` folders (and more depending on the project).

So something like this:

[image: Folder view in ZF2 application]

As far as I know this is the correct layout in a ZF2 application.

You can also read on folder structure [in the ZF2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.intro.html#basic-module-structure).
And on ZF2 project structure [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/ref/project.structure.html)
And on setting up a module [here in the ZF2 user guide](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.0.5/user-guide/modules.html)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what should have been done before starting the project. but now i have a whole project all as one block. and the task is to devide it into modules. My question is, is there a known strategies to do that, or it simply depends on the developer taste?

Comment: You should try to divide them by functionality. So all the stuff related to a certain application function (which can work independently) to a separate module. If your application is small and the functionality is all dependent it is okay to regard it as one module. You can than suffice with one Application module. In bigger projects you want [modular programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) because of [separation of concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and then you split it into independent modules.

Comment: Many Thanks, that was a sufficient answer. :)